# Memory management crash for a UIViewController embedded via addChild

Tags: ios, swift

I am seeing a very strange behavior where UIKit tries to retain a UIViewController that was embedded via `addChild` after it was released already.

To reproduce the issue, I isolated the problem in an example project [CardStackExample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d30u9f9swr5mahp/CardStackExample.zip?dl=1). It has a class `StackViewController` that manages a child view controllers. When you press the `Add Card` button, this adds a UIViewController as child. When a limit of 5 is reached, it removes the oldest controllers keeping only the newest 5. This is implemented in `StackViewController#enforceLimit`. When pressing the button 7 times with zombies enabled you can see it crashing in a UIKit internal routine `_runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks`:

```
2019-04-22 14:31:20.345319+0200 CardStackExample[84434:1400814] *** -[UIViewController retain]:
message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fbb99c1bc10
```

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x000000010cb7e378 in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x000000010cb80238 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#2  0x000000010cbf867e in +[__NSArrayI __new::::] ()
#3  0x000000010cb677b0 in -[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:] ()
#4  0x00000001107e6d5b in _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks ()
#5  0x00000001107d6199 in _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks ()
#6  0x000000011080332b in _afterCACommitHandler ()
#7  0x000000010cae00f7 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#8  0x000000010cada5be in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#9  0x000000010cadac31 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#10 0x000000010cada302 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#11 0x0000000113dce2fe in GSEventRunModal ()
#12 0x00000001107dbba2 in UIApplicationMain ()
#13 0x000000010a0925bb in main at /Users/ralf/tmp/CardStackExample/CardStackExample/App/AppDelegate.swift:4
#14 0x000000010df81541 in start ()
```

Which is super strange because the implementation uses absolutely nothing suspicious that might lead to a memory management bug like unowned references. Especially the `enforceLimit` method which seems to be causing this is quite simple:

```swift
    func enforceLimit() {
        if children.count > self.cardLimit {

            let oldestControllers = self.children.dropLast(self.cardLimit)

            for controller in oldestControllers {
                debugPrint("removing controller", controller)
                controller.willMove(toParent: nil)
                controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
                controller.removeFromParent()
            }

        }
    }
```

I am quite baffled by this issue. It looks like a bug internally in UIKit or the stdlib or in ARC where the UIViewController is released too early. But as the code is quite simple I doubt that... Any hints? Did I miss something obvious here?

I played around with this example quite a bit to try to track down the root cause. The following clues I found:

- it works on iOS 10, crashes on iOS 11/12
- It doesn't crash when I implement the `enforceLimit` method differently:

```
    func enforceLimit() {
        while children.count > self.cardLimit {
            let controller = children[0]
            controller.willMove(toParent: nil)
            controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
            controller.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
```

- It only starts crashing with the cardLimit set to 5, for a cardLimit of 3 or 4 it works fine.

Comment: Happens with Xcode 10.2 and 10.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm.... not sure if this is an ARC "bug" or a "gotcha".

It appears to be related to the view controller reference held in `oldestControllers`.

If I use your second method, no problems:

```
func enforceLimit() {

    if self.children.count > self.cardLimit {

        while children.count > self.cardLimit {
            let controller = children[0]
            controller.willMove(toParent: nil)
            controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
            controller.removeFromParent()
        }

    }

}
```

However, if I simply add your `oldestControllers` line, without doing anything with it or referencing it in any other manner:

```
func enforceLimit() {

    if self.children.count > self.cardLimit {

        let oldestControllers = self.children.dropLast(self.cardLimit)

        while children.count > self.cardLimit {
            let controller = children[0]
            controller.willMove(toParent: nil)
            controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
            controller.removeFromParent()
        }

    }

}
```

I again get the original crash.

Seems like "Method 2" will do the job... unless you want to file a report with Apple to find out if it's a bug.

---

**Edit:**

After a little more reading / testing...

```
let oldestControllers = self.children.dropLast(self.cardLimit)
```

returns an `ArraySlice`. It's important to not that it is not a ***copy*** of the elements of the array:

> Important
>
> Long-term storage of ArraySlice instances is discouraged. A slice holds a reference to the entire storage of a larger array, not just to the portion it presents, even after the original array’s lifetime ends. Long-term storage of a slice may therefore prolong the lifetime of elements that are no longer otherwise accessible, which can appear to be memory and object leakage.

Even though this isn't what I'd refer to as "long-term storage" it *does* seem to apply to what's happening here.

Comment: The actual implementation of the class is way more complex (with animations / many different cases that are handled differently) and I am seeing similar crashes in other cases as well. So it's not so much about getting the job done - I isolated this one "wtf" case to find out and understand what's going on.

Comment: @RalfEbert "So it's not so much about getting the job done" So what kind of answer would satisfy you?

Comment: Hmm, first of all, I am very thankful for DonMag's answer and that he could reproduce the crash and the hint regarding to dropFirst / the ArraySlice. Hmm, I guess I am looking for an answer that explains why it crashes and if it's indeed a bug on Apple's side or if I the example violates some rule that I am unaware of. I want to understand what's going on :)

Comment: @RalfEbert Well if you just change your code to `Array(self.children.dropLast(self.cardLimit))` does the problem go away?

Comment: Regarding the ArraySlice: thanks for the hint, I wasn't aware of that. But still, in the worst case this might prolong the lifetime of the controller and the array. But I don't see how this can lead to such a crash where UIKit seems to hold a dangling pointer to the view controller...

Comment: No, it's the same with Array(...)

Comment: Hmm, maybe slicing into the children view controller list is a bad idea. Who knows what goes on with that list. `Array(self.children).dropLast(self.cardLimit)` f.e. prevents the crash. But would be interesting to know what goes on with that list :)

Comment: Yup, never create a slice into the UIViewController#children list, always make a copy of the list first, seems to be the rule to follow. This fixes the crashes also in the full component. Good to know, thanks for the help :)